# Out of Focus Nikon D3100 in movie mode

Tags: autofocus

I have a Nikon D3100 and recently it has had the out of focus issue, but only in the movie setting. It just does this part of the time. Thought it was battery, but it had a full charge. The A/M setting is A  and is still a problem. Only part of the time. Sometimes, it appears normal. Tried in manual (M) setting, NO better.  Did run the auto clean cycle in side the camera now. Anyone have another helpful thought?

Answer (score 2):

Your Nikon D3100 does not have the capability to automatically adjust focus continuously while shooting video. Most DSLRs from the same time frame don't have that ability either. The best you can do using autofocus is to focus the camera before beginning to record and maintain the same subject distance while recording.